# Query in MS Access - Percent of Sum

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table of tickers, the owner, and the number of shares, and want to produce a query showing total and percent of owner.

Here is dummy data:

```
+-------+--------+--------+
| Owner | Ticker | Shares |
+-------+--------+--------+
| Matt  | AAPL   |   2000 |
| Jed   | AAPL   |   8000 |
| Ron   | AAPL   |   4000 |
| Matt  | GE     |   3000 |
| Ron   | GE     |   1000 |
| Jed   | GOOG   |   5000 |
+-------+--------+--------+
```

And here is how I would like it to be:

```
+--------+--------------+------+------+-----+
| Ticker | Total Shares | Matt | Jed  | Ron |
+--------+--------------+------+------+-----+
| AAPL   |        14000 | 14%  | 57%  | 29% |
| GE     |         4000 | 75%  | 0%   | 25% |
| GOOG   |         5000 | 0%   | 100% | 0%  |
+--------+--------------+------+------+-----+
```

Comment: Please add some code to show how you have attempted to solve this problem.

Comment: I did a cross-tab query with ticker (group by) and total shares (sum of shares) as row headings and owner (group by) as column heading.  If i add shares as a value and choose sum, i get the number value where I want the percent.  Access doesnt give percent as an option in the drop down so I tried Expression.     writing the expression i went shares/ sum of shares but Access it not accepting that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to solve this is using conditional aggregation.

Since you want the results by `ticker`, you `group by` the `ticker` field in column 1, `sum` the `shares` field to obtain column 2, and then use `iif` statements to calculate the percentage ownership for each of the remainining columns:

```
select
    t.ticker,
    sum(t.shares) as [Total Shares],
    sum(iif(t.owner='Matt',t.shares,0))/sum(t.shares) as Matt,
    sum(iif(t.owner='Jed',t.shares,0))/sum(t.shares) as Jed,
    sum(iif(t.owner='Ron',t.shares,0))/sum(t.shares) as Ron
from
    YourTable t
group by
    t.ticker
order by
    t.ticker
```

You can use formatting to convert the resulting decimal values into percentages.

Note that this approach does not scale well, as you are hard-coding field values into the query itself, but this approach is inevitable when transposing rows to columns, which goes against how most RDBMS like to operate.

A more scalable method might be to either use a correlated subquery, e.g.:

```
select  
    t1.ticker,
    t1.owner, 
    t1.shares/(select sum(t2.shares) from YourTable t2 where t2.ticker = t1.ticker) as pct
from 
    YourTable t1
```

Or a join on a query which calculates the total shares for each ticker, e.g.:

```
select t1.ticker, t1.owner, t1.shares/t2.shares as pct
from
    YourTable t1 inner join
    (
        select t.ticker, sum(t.shares) as shares 
        from YourTable t 
        group by t.ticker
    ) t2
    on t1.ticker = t2.ticker
```

Comment: Thanks Lee.  I tried this in the SQL view of MS Access and in SQL developer and couldnt get it to work.  I'm going to keep trying

Comment: Thank you!  It was user error.   If you have any ideas for a scalable way, I would be all ears, as I have approximately 15 groups with between 3 and 7 owners

Comment: Lee, you are awesome.   This was so helpful.   I really appreciate it.

Comment: Thank you for your kind words, I'm really glad it helped.